# How to create an String ArrayList in Java with a repeating pattern

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I create a `String ArrayList` with a repeated group of strings like

```
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", ......
```

In Python I use

```
list = deque(["A","B","C"]*288) # 288 times "A","B","C"
```

Comment: you could create an empty `ArrayList` and  add the `String`s with a `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without complicating things, Use a simple for loop:

```
ArrayList<String> alphabets = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0; i<288; i++) {
    alphabets.add("A");
    alphabets.add("B");
    alphabets.add("C");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use an `IntStream` to create a range of 288 items, and then flatmap it to though three strings:

```
List<String> strings = IntStream.range(0, 288)
                                .boxed()
                                .flatMap(i -> Stream.of("A", "B", "C"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 288; i++) {
    arrayListName.add((3 * i), "A");
    arrayListName.add((3 * i + 1), "B");
    arrayListName.add((3 * i + 2), "C");
}
```